# how to deal with the war name when deploy eureka client in tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

when we deploy a eureka client web server in tomcat,it's path may be `hostname:port/project_name/**`

but when route by zuul with eureka `service-id` , zuul always ignore the `project_name`

and how can I config this this `project_name` in eureka client or zuul?

Answer (score 0):

In zuul configuration, you can preserve the prefix in url with `stripPrefix` option. Its default value is true, namely it will remove your project_name in url. If you change `stripPrefix` to `false` like below example, your eureka client will receive the full url that was passed to zuul server.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    service-a:
      path: /service-a/**  
      stripPrefix: false
```

Comment: then I have to hardcode the project_name in zuul, can eureka automatically discovery the project name or the eureka client tell the eureka server?

Comment: Each eureka client reports it's service id (application name) with hostname and port. When zuul decides to route, try to match the configured `path` with request url and choose the route. Each route has service id. In above my configuration, service-a (a child of routes) is the service id. Zuul forwards the request to the host and port that has the same service id. As default, when zuul forwards request, it strip the matched url prefix. That's why you need to specify stripPrefix as false in your case.

Comment: u put the project_name in the path in your example, and i want to avoid that.so that the client who connect to zuul won't feel the systems behind.

Comment: it seems that eureka won't updated this issue [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/737)